# Wordpress Feed Creator Name Tag Full Name Instead Of First Name

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am parsing a Wordpress feed in my iOS application. I don't know much about Wordpress and its customisation. The feed shows the author name as below:

```
<dc:creator>andy</dc:creator>
```

while i want it to show the full name of the author in the feed like:

```
<dc:creator>andy rubin</dc:creator>
```

Can anybody point out where I can go to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `dc:creator` author names by visiting the the user profile settings and change the display name:

[image]

where you have filled out the first/last name text fields.